Stein Analysis 3.5.2 - kernels with average zero
Consider the problem given below from Stein and Shakarchi's Real analysis. Here is the same question being asked before, but my attempt is different, so I wanted to ask as a new post. I want to know if this solution is correct.

Proof: Since $|K_{\delta}(y)|\leq A\delta/|y|^{d+1}$, we have $K_{\delta}(y)\rightarrow 0$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0 $ $\forall y$. Then notice $|f(x-y)K_{\delta}(y)|\leq A'|f(x-y)|$ for $A'$ a constant not depending on $\delta$ (it exists by the first $2$ properties, and a proof is also given in text). Then since the upper bound of the $\delta$ indexed functions $|f(x-y)K_{\delta}(y)|$ is integrable w.r.t $y$, by the dominated convergence theorem, we have $(f*K_{\delta})(x) = \int f(x-y)K_{\delta}(y)dy \rightarrow \int 0dy = 0$ as $\delta \rightarrow 0$. (Think of $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$ with $n \rightarrow \infty$).
As I said above, I wonder if this is a correct proof. One issue is that, I never used the fact that average is zero.
